# c# - Read video file data

Tags: c#, video, encoding, codec

I was curious, if there are some good explanations (tutorials) about processing video files? I know that there are many libraries that gives you control over video from file. But I would like to get my hands on the raw way of processing video file. Something like read video information metadata, process input stream bytes to frames etc.

Comment: in other words you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: There are hundreds of formats. What one do you want to start with?

Comment: Lets say ".avi". Point of the question is to get complex idea about the structure of the formats. So some good tutorials to begin with ;)